# How to merge file in to one with "enter"(New line) in windows batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, merge

Good morning guys,

I am going to merge 3 files into one. But I tested script as below:

```
Del Worker_all_for.dat
Type Worker1.dat > Worker_all_for.dat
echo >> Worker_all_for.dat
Type Worker2.dat >> Worker_all_for.dat
echo. >> Worker_all_for.dat
Type Worker3.dat >> Worker_all_for.dat
```

But I cannot add "break" between each file.

For example:

```
Worker1.dat
1
2
Worker2.dat
3
4
Worker4.dat
5
6
```

The Worker_all_for.dat will be the:

```
1
23
45
6
```

But my purpose is to get:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

I did a search, but I just can find on Unix, not On windows.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any reason why the last line of each file does not have a terminating carriage return or line feed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the command `echo.` to print a new line.

```
Del Worker_all_for.dat
Type Worker1.dat > Worker_all_for.dat
echo. >> Worker_all_for.dat
Type Worker2.dat >> Worker_all_for.dat
echo. >> Worker_all_for.dat
Type Worker3.dat >> Worker_all_for.dat
```